# WIndows universal app with system.drawing and possible alternative

Tags: windows, system.drawing, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm developing a windows universal app and i need to work with Bitemap but

i cannot seem to reference System.Drawing,

Why cant windows universal app cannot reference this dll and what alternative do i have?

**Edit**
Any suggestions on how can i use my already written filtering library (that depends on system.drawing) in a universal app?

Tnx

Comment: You'll have to stop trying, you can't use that namespace in a Universal app.  It isn't universal.  Use the Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging namespace instead.

Comment: And what are you trying to use it for? Alternatives depend on your goal.

Comment: @Passant tnx alt; i am building an image filtering app. for that i need to manipulate Bitemap objects - is that still supported?

Comment: i've edited my question - please respond in an answer so i can mark it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.Drawing` is the .NET namespace for working with GDI+. This technology is not available for Windows Store apps or universal Windows Apps. See [.NET for Windows apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx).

You can make use of the [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) project for a WinRT wrapper usable from C# for drawing with Direct2D/DirectWrite which are also supported for Windows Store apps and UWP. 
See [Introducing Win2D: GPU accelerated 2D graphics programming in the Windows Runtime](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/09/05/introducing-win2d-gpu-accelerated-2d-graphics-programming-in-the-windows-runtime/).

You can make use of [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) which provides wrappers for Direct2D, DirectWrite, and the Windows Imaging Component (WIC).

**In short:** You can't use an existing library that makes use of `System.Drawing` in a universal Windows Application.

Comment: Tnx, although that's a shame.. is there any way around it?

Comment: Rewrite the library to use something that is supported.

Comment: The examples just seem to show the use of canvas. I just need to edit the file in memory no need to display it to the user :/.

Answer (score 0):

[Cross platform System.Drawing](https://github.com/CoreCompat/CoreCompat)

This may not directly address the question. The project makes System.Drawing available to Linux and Mac osX10. Having support for UWP platform could help the transition to Windows.UI while porting/testing code from WinForm to UWP.