# MCG0023:UnresolvableAssemblyReference - Unable to build in release mode

Tags: uwp, release, system.drawing

We are trying to build our project in release mode but we got this error :

```
Internal compiler error: MCG0023:UnresolvableAssemblyReference Unresolvable assembly reference 'Assembly(Name=System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)' found. Please check the references in your build system. A reference is either missing or an assembly is missing an expected type.
```

We are aware that [*System.Drawing* cannot be used in UWP apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545389/windows-universal-app-with-system-drawing-and-possible-alternative) and it seems that there is no reference to this assembly in our UWP project.

However, we reference at some point another WPF project (through an executable, 32bits) that uses the **System.Drawing** dll. 
We simply add this project to our authorized extensions in the **Package.appxmanifest**, in the node */Package/Applications/Application/Extensions/* :

```
<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="OurExternalApplication.exe" />
```

Is there a way to find out where did this issue come from ?

**Note :** We use an external solution, Syncfusion for UWP, that references at some points this assembly. But there is no problem to build other projects using Syncfusion in release. And as Davis Jebaraj point out in his answer, there is no know issue in the UWP specific dll, since it implements the required System.Drawing classes.

Comment: Could you please provide a simple demo for reproducing this issue?

Comment: As I said, I cannot reproduce this issue in any of our other test projects - even with the same references, it only happens on our main project.

Answer (score 1):

As System.Drawing is not available in UWP, we (Syncfusion) have implemented the required System.Drawing classes in our Pdf.UWP assembly itself. We haven't seen this reference issue till now.

Syncfusion provides Syncfusion.Pdf.UWP.dll for UWP compatibility. Can you confirm that you are using this assembly in your UWP project (and not Syncfusion.Pdf.Base.dll)

[Documentation link](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/assemblies-required)

Comment: We are indeed using Syncfusion.Pdf.UWP.dll for the UWP part. There is no issue in any of our other test projects using Syncfusion so I assume that this thread's isn't due to this reference. Thank you for enlightening us on this point.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the System.Drawing Namespace isn't available in UWP. You could check the official document [.NET for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185501.aspx) But you said `Syncfusion for UWP, that references at some points this assembly`, which library? I'm not sure if the syncfusion has some cooperation with Microsoft. If you make sure that syncfusion has used System.Drawing Namespace APIs in their library, you might need to ask on their [official forum](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/uwp). Their developer team might know some useful information about this.

Comment: The fact is that we can find the text "System.Drawing" when searching in our complete solution. There is a lot of Syncfusion's DLL in the matching files but there is no problem to compile in release mode in other project using the same reference. The search also returned some other files such as an executable in folder $(SolutionPath)/bin/x64/Release/($ProjectName).exe. The only file that is not in the "/bin" folder is a Syncfusion DLL that we need to copy, "Syncfusion.Pdf.Base.dll".

Note : We use Syncfusion v14.4.0.20.

Comment: I don't know about this. You could ask on their official forum.