# System.Drawing error on Save image from byte data

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

Error converting a byte data to image in a UWP application

Tried to get the stream from the data and converting that to image but Error!

The error is:

> system.drawing is not supported on this platform

```cs
 videoParser.Initialize(delegate (byte[] data)
 {
       using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(data))
       {
           System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mStream);
           img.Save(@"D:/img.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
       }
       return DJISDKManager.Instance.VideoFeeder.ParseAssitantDecodingInfo(0, data);
 });
```

I want to save the image in jpeg format

Comment: system.drawing is not supported on this platform

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545389/windows-universal-app-with-system-drawing-and-possible-alternative

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use IFormFile

```
  private string SaveImage(Guid AdID, IFormFile Photo)
    {
        if (Photo != null)
        {
            string uploadFolder = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "AdsImages");
            string UniqueFileName = AdID.ToString() + "_" + Photo.FileName;
            string FilePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, UniqueFileName);
            Photo.CopyTo(new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create));
            return UniqueFileName;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where do I use the byte[] data here?

Answer (score 0):

From the link @Amy shared, it seems that System.Drawing is not available for universal Windows Apps. If you only want to save the image from the data, you can first create a file and then write the bytes in it.

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"D:\");
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("img.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, data);
```

Comment: I get a System.UnauthorizedAccessException on GetFolderFromPathAsync..

Comment: When you tried to access folder by path, have you added the broadFileSystemAccess capability and configued access in Settings > Privacy > File system to allow your app to access the file system?

Comment: I guess I cannot add broadFileSystemAccess to my Package.appxmanifest
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations?redirectedfrom=MSDN#special-and-restricted-capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations?redirectedfrom=MSDN#special-and-restricted-capabilities)

Comment: If you want to submit an app to the store, broadFileSystemAccess indeed is not a good choice, it will be strictly reviewed. You can use FileSavePicker to create file, it will open a dialog that similar to file explorer, then you could create a file from the location you want. Or you can save a file in localFolder(`ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("img.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);`).