# System.Drawing is not found in Assemblies at all

Tags: uwp

In my UWP code, I used System.Drawing as below.

```
using System.Drawing;
```

And in my .csproj project file, if I set TargetPlatformMinVersion to be 10.0.17763.0, then things go right. But if I set TargetPlatformMinVersion to be 10.0.15063.0, then I get this compile error:

> The type or namespace name 'Drawing' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System'

```
     <TargetPlatformVersion Condition=" '$(TargetPlatformVersion)' == '' ">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
-    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
+    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.15063.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

I searched StackOverflow, post like this:
[System.drawing namespace not found under console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553136/system-drawing-namespace-not-found-under-console-application)
It suggests to find the System.Drawing by this way:

> Project -> Right Click -> Add -> Reference -> Assemblies -> Search
>   "System.Drawing"

But I failed to find it at all, please check the picture below. How to solve it?

[image]

Comment: no you cant use system.Drawing in UWP [refer the answer for alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31557036/11362349)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the Type under the `System.Drawing` namespace, you need to set the minimum version of UWP to 16299 and above.

If you have to set the minimum version of the app to 15063, you can consider using `Win2D.uwp` instead of `System.Drawing`, you can download it in [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Win2D.uwp).

Best regards.